# Computed column on table is giving error when triggers are used on table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am getting below error and if I don't use computed column then it works fine .

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Procedure test1tri, Line 3 [Batch Start Line 24]
> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

this is sample I am using:

```
drop table test2 
CREATE TABLE test2 ([ID] [INT], [NAME] [VARCHAR](100), [ADDRESS] [VARCHAR](100)
  CONSTRAINT [PK_test2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY] 
)ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE test2
ADD full_name AS (name + ' ' + address) persisted;

drop table test3
CREATE TABLE test3 ([$delete] [bit] NULL,[ID] [INT], [NAME] [VARCHAR](100), [ADDRESS] [VARCHAR](100)
CONSTRAINT [PK_test3] UNIQUE CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE test3
ADD full_name AS (name + ' ' + address)  persisted;

CREATE TRIGGER [test1tri] ON [test2]
INSTEAD OF INSERT AS 
INSERT INTO [test3] SELECT 0,* FROM inserted

GO
```

Comment: The error complains about bad syntax, not triggers

Comment: `INSERT INTO [test3] SELECT 0,*` which value goes into what column? Even if the tables had the same number of columns (they don't), you'd end up trying to write to the computed columns. Specify the column names explicitly

Comment: No syntax is correct, tables are succesfully created on database, but when I try to create a trigger it throws an error, and I remove computed colums on both the tables then trigger will succesfully created

Comment: If the syntax was correct you wouldn't get a syntax error complaining about the wrong number of columns

Comment: select 0, mean it will store in $delete column  of table [test3]

Comment: Because you can't insert into a computed column. You should always fully specify the names of the columns your are inserting into, and the names of the columns you are selecting. Never just `insert into table select`, and never `select *`, instead `insert into table col1, col2 etc, select col1, col2 etc`

Comment: You are trying to insert 5 columns into a 4 column table, *and* trying to write to a calculated column. Specify the columns explicitly, excluding the calculated column

Comment: Actullay at run time triggers are not able to read computed column , that could be the reason but I am not sure , If not then I need solution for this.

Comment: We already replied. Specify the columns. `INSERT INTO Table (Col1,Col2,ColeCol4) SELECT Value1,Col1,Col2 FROM ...`

Comment: `select 0, *` *doesn't* mean that 0 will go into the `$delete` column. It means that `SELECT` will return columns in an unspecified order which probably *doesn't* match the target table. `INSERT` without a column list means you have no way of knowing which column will match which one, and may end up trying to store text into numeric columns, or write into calculated columns

Comment: Thanks for the response and  Just wanted to know how can we write trigger for my above code because below this give error saying  Invalid pseudocolumn "$delete". <br/>

CREATE TRIGGER [test1tri] ON [test2]
INSTEAD OF INSERT AS 
INSERT INTO [test3] ($delete,ID,NAME,ADDRESS) select 0,ID, NAME,ADDRESS  from inserted

GO

Comment: Use `[$delete]` i.e. with `[]`'s as you did when creating it.

Comment: Thanks Dale, It worked I appreaciate it. One last question if you please can tell in simple words , why do we use select 0,*  As I can see  at my code base  all around , I did not get much , answered by Panagiotis above so.

Comment: I would never use `select 0,*` because as I said more than once, I always specify every column name, because then you avoid having the very issue you've just had. Not specifying the columns names makes it confusing (now) and prone to breaking (in the future) if you change your table definition. Always specify all column names and you will have robust code.

Comment: I am sorry I confused you here , I meant was In what situtation we use  select 0 ?

Comment: I don't know why you are using `select 0`? Why are you? You are inserting it into a column called `$delete`, and you are selecting from the `inserted` table, meaning its not a delete, maybe thats why you are inserting `0` into that column? But sorry I don't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

While you want to insert new record to table you should not provide value for the computed column. So you can rewrite your trigger as below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [test1tri] ON [test2]
INSTEAD OF INSERT AS 

INSERT INTO [test3] SELECT   0,
                             Inserted.ID,
                             Inserted.NAME,
                             Inserted.ADDRESS FROM inserted

GO
```

Comment: OK, Thanks Got it, Now my question is little different from above and it is about replication;I have already configured all publisher and subscriber.

Let say I have publication table_1 with 4 column (where 1 is computed coulmn) on DB 1 and On DB2 I  have subscription  table_2 with same structure (4 column) but no computed column. So Now when I do any insert operation on table_1 then on table_2 data will reflect? as this is not working for me!
Or do I need to create table_2 with the compulsory computed column?

Comment: @ujjwal_jain No, you do not need to add the compulsory computed column on the subscribers side. Basically, replication is a bit different from trigger, so I think you will be in good direction, if you post a new question, focused on replication and computed column. However if you find the abovementioned answer, as an answer to your posted question, then it might be good if you mark it as answer too. Regards.